# getting value of dynamically created textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a order page, where customer selects product from a variety of categories then using a php foreach loop I am getting the selected products details from the database and show the selected products in step 2, where quantity is to be selected. In step two I need to calculate the subtotal of the product i.e. quantity * rate(fetched from db). I am unable to write the working javascript code for that.

```
<input type="text"  name="qty<?php echo $index; ?>" maxlength="7" class="bo-text" onblur = "getnsetvalue(<?php echo $sp; ?>, <?php echo $index; ?>);"> // the textbox where quantity is added

<input type="text"  readonly name="subtotal<?php echo $index; ?>" maxlength="7" class="bo-text"> //the texbox where subtotal will be computed and displayed
```

The javascript code that I am using is:

```
function getnsetvalue(rate, index){
        var quantity_field = "qty" + index;
        var quantity = document.product2.quantity_field.value;      
        var stotal = parseFloat(rate*quantity);
        var target_field = "subtotal" + index;
        document.product2.target_field.value=stotal;
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide an html example. and more details about "unable to write the working javascript". you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function getnsetvalue(rate, index){
    var quantity_field = "qty" + index;
    var quantity = document.getElementsByName(quantity_field)[0].value      
    var stotal = parseFloat(rate*quantity);
    var target_field = "subtotal" + index;
    document.getElementsByName(target_field)[0].value=stotal;
}
```

Note: Your vars quantity_field,target_field aren't objects - they are just strings which can be used to find the wanted object.

Answer (score 0):

You should try onchange event instead of onblur. And make sure your input rate and index, both  of those are not null